# How to call uipangesture when the scrollview is scrolling?

Tags: ios, uiscrollview, uipangesturerecognizer

I want to change a `UIScrollView`'center via `UIPanGestureRecognizer`. The scroll view is scrolling vertically. And I pan it horizontally. The question is how to detect a `UIPanGestureRecognizer` when the scrollview is still scrolling???
Thank you in advance!

Comment: You want to change UIScrollView's center(move the whole UIScrollView) or you want to change UIScrollView's contentOffset set when you pan?

Comment: well,I just want to change it's center to change the whole uiscrollview's position.It is hard to decete the pangesture when scrollview is scrolling.Actually,at first I use touch events to move the scrollview and override touch events in uiscrollview's subview,but it didn't work.

Comment: I've edited my answer, you can check whether this works.

Answer (score 0):

**Edit:** You can customize your `UIScrollView` and override this method:

```
#import "MyScrollView.h"

@implementation MyScrollView

- (BOOL)touchesShouldCancelInContentView:(UIView *)view
{
    return YES;
}

@end
```

---

```
self.panGesture = [[UIPanGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(handlePan:)];
self.panGesture.delegate = self;
[self.view addGestureRecognizer:self.panGesture];

- (void)handlePan:(UIGestureRecognizer *)gestureRecognizer
{
    if (gestureRecognizer.state == UIGestureRecognizerStateEnded) {
        CGPoint offset = self.scrollView.contentOffset;
        offset.y = self.scrollView.contentSize.height/2;
        self.scrollView.contentOffset = offset;
    }
}

- (BOOL)gestureRecognizer:(UIGestureRecognizer *)gestureRecognizer shouldReceiveTouch:(UITouch *)touch
{
    return YES;
}
```

Comment: NO.This method can not work when the scrollview is scrolling.

Comment: Can you try my code again? I've tested it and I'm sure handlePan: is called. You need just to change scroll view's center not the content offset.

Comment: I know it's called when the scrollview's indicoter is disappeared.I think we can exchanged with email.We r all Chinese.AH...

Comment: Email me or add MSN using my email address.